# Несколько запросов в рамках одной сессии asp.net

Tags: asp.net, http, post, сессия, request

Есть задача обратиться к серверу, получить ответ, затем в той же сессии ещё раз обратиться к серверу. Это необходимо, так как таким образом выполняется авторизация.
Мой код выдаёт ошибку на втором GetRequestStream о том, что поток недоступен для записи. Что нужно сделать, чтобы сессия сохранялась и я мог отправить второй запрос в рамках этой сессии?
Первый ответ сервера корректный, говорящий о том, что я успешно авторизовался.

```
    public ActionResult Regs()
    {
        string url = "url";
        string postData = "postData";
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            requestWriter2.Write(postData);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        string responseData = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        postData = "second_postData";
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            requestWriter2.Write(postData);
        }
        resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        ViewBag.RD = responseData;
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, проблема решается просто. Делаю куки контейнер:

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Привязываю его к первому запросу:

```
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

Затем после получения ответа создаю второй запрос и привязываю тот же контейнер к нему:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest1.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

Всё отрабатывает штатно, ответы корректные.