# wininet несколько запросов в одном коннекте

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, wininet

Используя WinInet я делаю запросы к серверу. Насколько понял, то функция HttpSendRequest подключается к серверу отправляет запрос и получает ответ, после чего коннект закрывается сразу или через некоторое время. Мне нужно отослать несколько запросов при одном коннекте. В msdn написано что можно повторно слать запрос функцией HttpSendRequest и она отошлет в том же коннекте, но отошлет тот же самый запрос, а мне нужно разные запросы. WinInet позволяет менять сам запрос, но я не нашел как сменить тип запроса GET или POST и сменить сам урл. Можно создать новый запрос, но он будет создавать новый коннект, а мне нужно в уже существующем.
Есть похожий вопрос [Несколько запросов в рамках одной сессии asp.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900796/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8-asp-net) но это для .Net, а мне нужно для WinApi

Comment: Смену  URL вроде бы можно осуществить функцией InternetOpenUrlA, там есть и возможно нужный Вам флаг - INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT: Пытается использовать существующий объект InternetConnect, если он существует с теми же атрибутами, необходимыми для выполнения запроса.

Comment: Советую изучать winsock2. Да сложнее, НО  зато даёт некоторые весомые преимущества!(по моему мнению)